# Site wide error management with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, error-handling

### The problem

I want to have a default error handler in my app that handles all unexpected errors but some time (for example when saving a model) there are many errors that can be expected so I want to handle them in a custom way rather than show a generic error page.

### My previous solution

My `Backbone.sync` function used to have this:

```
if(options.error)
  options.error(response)
else
  app.vent.trigger('api:error', response) # This is the global event channel
```

However, this no longer works since backbone always wraps the error function so it can trigger the `error` event on models.

### New solution 1

I could overwrite the `fetch` and `save` methods on models and collections to wrap `options.error` and have the code above there but this feels kinda ugly.

### New solution 2

Listen to `error` on models, this won't allow me to override the default error handler though.

### New solution 3

Pass in a custom option to disable the global triggering of the errors, this feels redundant though.

---

Have I missed anything? Is there a recommended way of doing this?

---

I can add that I'm using the latest version from their git repo, not the latest from their home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do this in your overridden sync?  This seems to accomplish the same thing you did before.

```
// error is the error callback you passed to fetch, save, etc.
var error = options.error;
options.error = function(xhr) {
  if (error) error(model, xhr, options);
  // added line below.
  // no error callback passed into sync.
  else app.vent.trigger('api:error', xhr); 

  model.trigger('error', model, xhr, options);
};
```

This code is from Backbone source, I only add the `else` line.

EDIT:

This is not the prettiest solution, but might work for you.  Create a new Model base class to use, instead of extending Backbone.Model, extend this.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

  // override fetch. Do something similar for save, destroy.
  fetch: function(options){
     options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
     var error = options.error;
     options.error = function(model, resp) {
       if (error) error(model, resp);
       else app.vent.trigger('api:error', resp); 
     };

     return Backbone.Model.prototype.fetch.apply(this, [options]);
  },
});

var MyModel = Model.extend({});
var model = new MyModel();
model.fetch(); // error will trigger 'api:error'
```

Actually, this might be better than overriding `sync` anyways.

Possible alternative is to use this: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/.
But with that, you will get the error regardless of whether you passed in an error callback to backbone fetch/save/destroy.

Comment: The problem is that options.error is always defined since Backbone creates it.

Comment: Yes, but `var error = options.error` is the error passed into `sync`, so checking `error` and not `options.error` should work.  If you don't pass in an error callback to save, fetch, etc., it will trigger 'api:error' if there is an error.

Comment: I'm using the latest in their master branch so it always wraps the error: http://jsfiddle.net/fFtrC/

Comment: Ok, that certainly changes things.

Comment: @NicklasA. Updated answer, actually I like this solution better than overriding sync.  A bit more code, but you don't have to mess with `sync`.

Comment: Yeah, that is my current solution, though you have to overwrite fetch, save and destroy on both models and collection (collections only have fetch). I'll let this question be for a while and accept your answer if nothing better comes along. Thanks.